# Does making an array filled with dictionaries create duplicate dictionaries in Python?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am trying to create a `list` filled with `dictionary` so that I can update each related dictionaries for making and `adjacency list` for a Graph. However, like below, whenever I try to update the dictionary, every dictionary in the array gets updated when I only want that specific dictionary in that related index to be updated. Does making dictionaries inside a `list` create duplicate dictionaries? How can I get around with this problem?

```
>>> a = [{}] * 4
>>> a[0].update({1:4})
>>> a
[{1: 4}, {1: 4}, {1: 4}, {1: 4}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[{} for _ in range(4)]
```

will create copies instead of references